# Easier proof that if a commutative ring has only two ideals it is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

So I was reviewing for my algebra exam, and one of the review questions was: if a commutative ring has only two ideals is it a field?

I've seen a couple proofs, but the proof I constructed seems like a simpler, although not necessarily more intuitive proof:

Let R be a commutative ring with two ideals.

1) consider R X R.

2) let I = {(a,0) such that a is in R}

3) I is maximal in R X R since R's only ideals are (1), and (0).

4) let F = R X R / I

5) F = {(0,b) + I such that b is in R}

6) F is a field since R X R is a commutative ring, and I is a maximal ideal in this ring.

7) F is isomorphic to R by f : R X R / I -> R, f((0,b) + I) = b

8) since F is a field and R is isomorphic to F, R is a field.

Comment: Why not just argue: if $R$ isn't a field, then there's some noninvertible $r\in R$, but then $(0)\subsetneq (r)\subsetneq (1)$?

Comment: Or, using the same method but losing the bit about the direct product:  Since $(0), (1)$ are the only ideals, $(0)$ is maximal, so $R \cong R / (0)$ is a field

Comment: Honestly didn't think of that. I also didn't realize that you could let (0) be a maximal ideal, but that makes sense.

Comment: Hey Noah, is your argument that a noninvertible element multiplied by another noninvertible is always noninvertible, and so it forms, an ideal?

Comment: I don't think that's what @NoahSchweber is saying. His argument is that if $r$ is not invertible then $1$ is not in the ideal it generates.

Comment: @AviTachna-Fram Actually, a noninvertible element multiplied by *anything* is noninvertible. (And Ethan is right: this means that $1$, being invertible, is not in $(r)$ if $r$ is noninvertible.)